# Unable to send mail via MailGun to certain domains

Tags: email, mailgun

We are able to send mail normally but when sending via mailgun programmatically, it gets in accepted state but delivery fails. Reasons are:

1. Domain of sender address does not exist.
2. Sender address rejected: Domain not found